# Check if a certain type object exists in a list without a loop

Tags: python, list

I want to check if a certain object type is in a list, and I want to make without a loop for optimization purposes.

For example:

```
if list in Mylist:
    do something
```

Comment: Note that `in` still loops over the list. It's an O(n) operation, same as an explicit `for` loop.

Comment: How are you going to look at all the items in a list without iterating over them? That's not possible. What is your real question? This sounds like [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the value's type, so write a generator that does that

```
if list in (type(v) for v in Mylist):
    do something
```

This may not be faster. In fact, my tests show its slower on my machine. Here are some performance tests

```
from timeit import timeit

Mylist = list(range(30)) + [[1, 2, 3]]

def use_generator():
    return list in (type(v) for v in Mylist)

def use_for():
    for v in Mylist:
        if type(v) is list:
            return True
    return False

def use_generator_isinstance():
    return any(isinstance(v, list) for v in Mylist)

def use_for_isinstance():
    for v in Mylist:
        if isinstance(v, list):
            return True
    return False

print("generator", timeit("use_generator()", globals=globals()))
print("for", timeit("use_for()", globals=globals()))
print("generator isinstance", timeit("use_generator_isinstance()", globals=globals()))
print("for isinstance", timeit("use_for_isinstance()", globals=globals()))
```

output

```
generator 2.4875363089959137
for 1.4369069100066554
generator isinstance 2.4251753209973685
for isinstance 1.5919023430033121
```

In the case of the generator, a generator object is created and its `__next__` is called repeatedly. I think that explains its lower performance.

Comment: Yes, i know, but i'am looking for a way to do this whitout a loop. Is even possible?

Comment: @Xx_Prego_xX It's going to run a loop no matter how you do it.  It sounds like you just want to hide the loop from yourself so you aren't aware of it?  It's a questionable goal, but you can certainly use functions that implicitly loop over the list without a visible `for` if that's what you want.  Again, it's a highly questionable goal.

Comment: If the list is created by your own code, I guess you could also make a set and do something like `my_type_set.add(type(obj))` each time you add an object to the list.  Then checking for the presence of a type is O(1), but at the cost of creating the set in the first place, which would be O(N) anyway.

Comment: @Xx_Prego_xX - I don't understand. There was no explicit `for` loop here. There has to be a loop somewhere, though.

Comment: @Tom Karzes - Well, so, what wold be more optimized? using `map` or `loop`?

Comment: @Xx_Prego_xX - I think an explicit `for` is the fastest. The others are more compact but there are more method calls behind the curtains.

Comment: @Xx_Prego_xX - As for `map`, that is an ongoing battle in the python world. Python generators already do what `map` does and I think generators are preferred. Some people like the functional aspect of `map` but I am not one of those people.